# Not able to retrieve selected values from Django's Choicefield Form

Tags: django, django-forms

Following is my Django form

```
class Country(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    country = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id':'country'}))
```

Following is code before sending form to a HTML page

```
form = Country()
    choices = [('a', 'India'), ('b', 'United States of America')]
    form.fields['country'].choices = choices
    form.fields['country'].initial = 'b'
    return render(request,"Test.html",{"form":form})
```

Form is rendered properly in the front end and initial value is also set.
When user clicks submit button. It is throwing exception.

Following is the code i have written when user clicks submit button,

```
f = Country(request.POST)
print (f)
print("Country Selected: " + f.cleaned_data['country'])
```

I am getting the form like below when i printed the form after user submitted.

```
<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="ggg" id="id_name" required /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="country">Country:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. a is not one of the available choices.</li></ul><select name="country" id="country">
</select></td></tr>
```

Please help me with this. 
Thanks!

Comment: post the exception

Comment: Exception:  **'Country' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'**

Answer (score 1):

You add country choice in `get` method but not add it's in `post` method.When `post` form will take `a` or `b` as an invaild choice.
This is the  right way：

forms.py

```
class Country(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    country = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id':'country'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop('choices', None)
        initial = kwargs.pop('initial', None)
        super(Country, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].choices = choices 
        self.fields['country'].initial = initial
```

views.py:

```
kwarg = {
       'choices': [('a', 'India'), ('b', 'United States of America')],
       'initial': 'b',
}
if request.method == "POST":
    f = Country(request.POST, **kwarg)
    if f.is_vaild():
        # cleaned_data is generate after call is_vaild()
        print("Country Selected: " + f.cleaned_data['country'])
    else:
        print(f.errors.as_text())
else:
    form = Country(**kwarg)
return render(request,"Test.html",{"form":form})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to send the choices from view as an argument instead of hot coding. Could you please help me with that edit on top of your code

Comment: New answer with dynamic choices from views is updated!

Comment: Thanks! Please find the code where i have edited in your answer. I am facing an error saying **list object is not callable** in view.py before rendering HTML page. Could you please fix it

Comment: more info of except is need.

Comment: While creating instance to Country class by kwarg as an argument, it was throwing an exception saying that list object is not iterable. Refer to the code that I have edited in your reply